# Fetch or Push values from Parent application to Intents extension in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10, sirikit

I am creating a SiriKit extension for my application for a payment.

I want to fetch some data from parent application & use that data to populate.

How to fetch data from Parent application ?

Answer (score 0):

To share data between app and app extension, you should use App Groups.
Please refer following links:
http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Comment: Hi, is it possible to call web-service in Siri Intent Extension, to fetch data from Server?